# Arduino IDE code upload problem

Tags: usb, arduino

I have ubuntu 18.04 with the Arduino IDE .
The problem I always have is that when I want to upload a code and connect the USB cable from arduino to laptop ,I always get the same error:

The error:

```
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Device or resource busy
```

I always check the port in IDE. 
I have the 1.8.12 version ,I tested it with other versions ,but I had the same error.
With windows ,I didn't have this problem.
Why is this happening and how can I solve it?
It's very bad problem and I have to push the upload button(in IDE -> Ctrl+U) many times or to remove and then put again the cable in pc a lot of times .
So it takes me a minute to do all this thing
What should I do?
I'm desperate and angry with this problem.

Note: The same problem appeared with Ubuntu 19.04.

By the way,arduino IDE compile FASTER a big code than windows.
Ιncredible different time!!!
Thanks!!!

Comment: Just to be sure, have you updated the udev rules in /etc/udev/rules.d to allow your user to access the Arduino's serial port?

Comment: On which path is this located (example , hardware tools or where else) and how can I do this to have access ?

Comment: Ok, I take that as a "No". You should read [this](https://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/All/) to exclude any of that as a reason.

Comment: Are you a member of *dialout* group? For sure run `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER` and then retry. Which Arduino board do you have? Are you sure that it sits on ttyACM0?

Comment: I write these commands:sudo usermod -a -G dialout nikos ,then sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0 ,but I get the same error

Comment: Arduino Uno and in the port writes: /dev/ttyACM0(Arduino Uno) and when I remove the cable and then put it on pc again and try to upload the code ,I get the same error.On windows didn't have this problem.What else should I try?

Comment: OK ,it works...I write this command :  sudo apt-get --purge remove modemmanager and now it is uploading my code without any error.  I read that /dev/ttyACM0 conflicts with modemmanager.

Comment: Very good. Can you write this solution as an answer to your question so it becomes more visible?

Answer (score 0):

The ModemManager can conflict with `/dev/ttyACM0`. You have two options:

## Disable ModemManager temporarily

```
systemctl stop ModemManager.service
```

This will stop ModemManager *until the next reboot*. You will need to run this command every time you reboot your computer.

## Remove ModemManager completely

You can remove ModemManager completely, but this means you will not be able to use any modem with Ubuntu anymore. So if you use a USB modem for internet, **do not** remove the ModemManager.

This is what ModemManager does:

> ModemManager is a DBus-activated daemon which controls **mobile broadband (2G/3G/4G) devices and connections**. Whether built-in devices, USB dongles, bluetooth-paired telephones, or professional RS232/USB devices with external power supplies, ModemManager is able to prepare and configure the modems and setup connections with them.

If you are sure you will never use a Modem, run the following command to remove the modem completely:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove modemmanager
```

Answer (score -1):

After you write your code and compile it, open the terminal. 
If your port is, say, `ttyACM0`, run this:

```
ls /dev/ttyACM0
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

Enter your password at the prompt and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. And now, you're good to go and upload the code

Comment: If you read the comments you'll see that's what the OP tried already. Also, you shouldn't have to change rights on the device itself manually.